# Msbuild repeat task on condition

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a zip msbuild ZipDirectory task that generate a 1kb file sometimes although the expected output should be greater than 20 MB. Normally when I detect that problem and rerun the project the output is correct. The issue is that I have to manually and visually check the result. Is there a way of automatically checking the file size and run the zip task in loop until the correct output file size is detected?
I have already checked, and the problem is not the source directory content.

Below is a snippet similar to my project content

```
    <Project DefaultTargets="CreateZipPackage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <OutVersion>1.1.1.1</OutVersion>
    <OutDirAndVersion>$(OutDir)\$(OutVersion)</OutDirAndVersion>
    <WebAppPackagePath>$(OutDirAndVersion)\WebApp_$(OutVersion).zip</WebAppPackagePath>
    <Database1PackagePath>$(OutDirAndVersion)\Db1_$(OutVersion).Database.zip</Database1PackagePath>
    <Database2PackagePath>$(OutDirAndVersion)\Db2_$(OutVersion).Database.zip</Database2PackagePath>
    <Database3PackagePath>$(OutDirAndVersion)\Db3_$(OutVersion).Database.zip</Database3PackagePath>
    <ReleasePackageFolderPath>$(OutDir)\Interim_$(OutVersion)_Packages</ReleasePackageFolderPath>
    <ReleasePackagePath>$(OutDir)\Final_$(OutVersion).zip</ReleasePackagePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DeployablePackages Include="$(OutDirAndVersion)\*.zip" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CreateZipPackage">
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ReleasePackageFolderPath)" />
        <MSBuild Projects="WebApp.csproj" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="PackageLocation=$(WebAppPackagePath);PackageAsSingleFile=True;" />
        <MSBuild Projects="Db1.Database.sqlproj" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PackageLocation=$(Database1PackagePath);" />
        <MSBuild Projects="Db2.Database.sqlproj" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PackageLocation=$(Database2PackagePath);" />
        <MSBuild Projects="Db3.Database.sqlproj" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PackageLocation=$(Database3PackagePath);" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(DeployablePackages)" DestinationFolder="$(ReleasePackageFolderPath)" />
        <ZipDirectory SourceDirectory="$(ReleasePackageFolderPath)" DestinationFile="$(ReleasePackagePath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: How your task looks like?

Comment: Fix the actual problem: if you have the same input and different resulting ZIP file (sizes); then you're probably calling the ZIP task to early (or similar) so sometimes it does not see all the files it should include. When you call it again, everything (expected) is present and thus it has the size you expect. Maybe a missing dependency between Targets?